# Win32 BlockInput alternative on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, winapi

I'm implementing a simple Linux application.

I want to know, is there an alternative of the Win32 [`BlockInput()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput) on Linux?

I need to block the user's mouse and keyboard input.

Comment: Outside of malware, I'm not aware of a legitimate use case for `BlockInput` on Windows. Why do you need to port something that's of no utility in Windows to Linux? What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to block(disable) the user's keyboard and mouse input and enable it when for example (Ctrl + Alt + Del) is pressed. I just needed an API to do this in Linux. WinApi does the job for windows. Now want to know how can I achieve the same on Linux

Comment: @IInspectable To be fair, [`BlockInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput) does look like a kludge that drags the entire operating system into solving an application programming problem: handling synthetic mouse or keyboard events to an application without user input mucking them up - by blocking ***all*** input. How ... Microsoftian. I can imagine the X windows maintainers, the glibc maintainers, the committee overseeing the POSIX standard, and Linux Torvalds himself laughing at a request to add an API like that to Linux or POSIX.

Comment: @and *"handling synthetic mouse or keyboard events to an application without user input mucking them up"* - That's a solved problem. See [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput).

Comment: @IInspectable Perhaps a legitimate use case would be implementing some kind of remote desktop software with an option to prevent users from messing with the mouse/keyboard while their computer is being controlled through a remote connection? For example, TeamViewer has an option called "Disable remote input".

Comment: @hea The same effect can be accomplished by installing a low-level keyboard/mouse hook. While `BlockInput` literally invalidates all input, a hook can still respond to arbitrary input.